# Group week days array by common open hours

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays `Days` and `OpenTime`, how do I group the days based on the same open-time.

```
var Days = ["Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var OpenTime = ["09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "09:30-10:30", "09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "08:30-12:30", "12:00-16:00"];
```

This is the output I am hoping to get.

```
var output = ["Monday Wednesday Thursday 09:30-10:30", "Tuesday Friday Saturday 08:30-12:30", "Sunday 12:00-16:00"];
```

Thanks in advance.
P.S. Days and OpenTime changes with click-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a better structure, like and object with the dates as `key`.... then you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get each entry of your new object as an array with the form of `[key, value]` and then do the join to create the desired word.

working example here:

```js
var Days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var OpenTime = ["09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "09:30-10:30", "09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "08:30-12:30", "12:00-16:00"];

reducer = (accum, cv, index) => {
  // if the date doesnt have an entry, we create a new one
  if (!accum[cv]) {
    accum[cv] = []
  }

  // create an array with the previous values and the new one
  // in the first iteration it will be always => [ ...[], value]
  // but if the key matches a previous array it will be => [...[prevVal], value]
  accum[cv] = [...accum[cv], Days[index]];

  return accum;


}

const reduced = OpenTime.reduce(reducer, {});

const finalResult = Object.entries(reduced).map(([date, days]) => {
  return days.join(' ') + ' ' + date;
})

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: I know that the nature of the source data implies that the number of entries is limited, thus performance may not be an issue. However the pattern of using spread syntax to append items to array within `.reduce()` is rather controversial as it forces creation of new array upon each iteration. That is why, I guess, it makes sense to prefer some [faster](https://jsbench.me/vgkc1zzcyn/1) method.

Comment: totally agree @YevgenGorbunkov but the user never asked for performance, therefore I wasn't trying to do it like that, just put the first idea on my mind, but thanks to your correction, it is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### Compact and efficient solution

---

***Note***: *accepted solution uses anti-pattern (spread syntax) to append element to an array, which causes new array creation upon each loop iteration. It is the [slowest](https://jsbench.me/vgkc1zzcyn/1) among available approaches.*

---

Assuming `OpenTime` indexes correspond to respective items of `Days`, you may traverse `OpenTime` with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build up an object where keys will match open hours and values (arrays of indexes) will represent respective week days.

After that you may simply loop through that [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (e.g. with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to return the strings of desired format:

```js
const Days = ["Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
      OpenTime = ["09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "09:30-10:30", "09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "08:30-12:30", "12:00-16:00"],
      
      openTimeMap = OpenTime.reduce((r,t,i) => 
        (r[t]=r[t]||[], r[t].push(i), r),{}),
      result = Object
        .entries(openTimeMap)
        .map(([time, days]) => 
          `${days.map(i => Days[i]).join(' ')} ${time}`)
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: @yevgen-gorbunkov Thanks for the quick response. The only comment is that your code has no comments in it so that makes it a bit harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Days = ["Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
let OpenTime = ["09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "09:30-10:30", "09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "08:30-12:30", "12:00-16:00"];   

let transformed = OpenTime.reduce((result,ot,index,original)=>{
  let ti = result.findIndex(r=>r.time===ot);
  ti===-1 ? result.push({time:ot, days: [Days[index]]}) :result[ti].days.push(Days[index]);
  return result;
},[]).map(item=>(`${item.days.join(" ")} ${item.time}`));

console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Days = ["Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const OpenTime = ["09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "09:30-10:30", "09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "08:30-12:30", "12:00-16:00"];

checkDuplicateEntries = (array) => {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (duplicates.hasOwnProperty(array[i])) {
      duplicates[array[i]].push(i);
    } else if (array.lastIndexOf(array[i]) !== i) {
      duplicates[array[i]] = [i];
    }
  }
   return getPairedArray(duplicates);
}

getPairedArray = (obj) => {
    const pairedArray = [];
    for(const key in obj) {
        let timings = '';
        for(const index of obj[key]){
            timings += ` ${Days[index]}`;
        }
        timings += ` ${key}`;
        pairedArray.push(timings);
    }
    return pairedArray;
} 

console.log(checkDuplicateEntries(OpenTime));


// Hope this will help
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 and assuming that data structure for mapping the day to time can't be altered. Then:

```js
const Days = ["Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

const OpenTime = ["09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "09:30-10:30", "09:30-10:30", "08:30-12:30", "08:30-12:30", "12:00-16:00"];

// get all the common open time and merge in a smaller array
const uniqueOpenTimes = OpenTime.reduce((uniqueTimes, time) => !uniqueTimes.includes(time)? [...uniqueTimes, time] : uniqueTimes, []);


// Now do the nested loop successfully assuming that both arrays grow equally i.e. OpenTime and Days
const uniqueOpenTimesWithDay = uniqueOpenTimes.reduce((strArr, time) => {
  let daysStrings = "";
  Days.forEach((day, i) => {
    if (OpenTime[i] === time){
      daysStrings += `${day} `;
    }
  });
  daysStrings += time;
  strArr.push(daysStrings.trim())
  return strArr;
}, []);

console.log('uniqueOpenTimesWithDay', uniqueOpenTimesWithDay)
```